# Very fast thread-safe collection or in-memory db needed

Tags: .net, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, in-memory-database

I get data from external application:

```
class DataItem
{
   public string key;
   public int Attribute1;
   public string Attribute2;
}
```

One thread store it in collection.
Other threads (3-10) query collection by key (90%) and attributes (10%).

What is the best way to implement this If I have 10, 100, 1000+ items in collection?

Comment: what about a concurrent hash map? Also are you querying by just the key or a1/a2?

Comment: are the attributes/the key unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really wanting an in-memory database then [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) using the [managed data provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) would be your best option. However, I suspect in this case you would be okay with the [ConcurrenctDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). This collection could easily handle 1000+ items and many threads accessing it in parallel. The caveat with using this collection is that you can specify only one key for each entry in the collection. You may need to use separate collections for each attribute you want to lookup. Then again, if lookups by an attribute are infrequent enough then you could opt for enumerating the entire collection to find matching attributes without the need for separate collections.

Comment: If the attributes are different data types, you can't use them all as keys in a single dictionary. But you could create a separate ConcurrentDictionary for each attribute data-type you wanted to be able to query on.

Comment: If the attribs are same type but different domain you would also need separate Dictionaries.

Comment: You would probably want to use a separate dictionary anyway. Otherwise you could wind up with a match to an attribute you were not expecting.

Answer (score 4):

If the collection is immutable (read-only, never changing) after initialization, and the collection is initialized before any threads can get to it, you don't need to do anything special.  Multiple threads can read from a collection or dictionary concurrently without any problems.

Problems only arise when the shared object (collection) changes state as a result of actions by multiple threads.  Updating the collection while multiple threads are reading from it, or if the collection maintained internal cache lists or whatnot would create a problem for multithread access.

You don't even need explicit locks to protect the collection during intialization, if you set up the collection as a static object initialized in its static constructor.  .NET will guarantee that the class is initialized before first use.

You can save yourself a lot of headaches and work if you can redefine the problem so that the collection is immutable after initialization.

Comment: +1 agreed. You could maintain two collections: an original and a copy. The original is the dynamic one and the copy is always read-only. When you want to publish the new state of the original collection just copy it and assign the new reference to the appropriate variable. Make sure that variable is marked `volatile` and you would need no further synchronization mechanisms. And it would work for *any* collection type.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I've used the two-lists pattern many times when the shared collection is occasionally updated while in use (two lists not needed for immutable collections). Use InterlockedExchange to swap the list pointers to guarantee read-modify-write atomicity on the global pointer var.

Answer (score 0):

Is the in-memory collection intended to be read only? It will make a difference in what you end up using.

My recommendations -
**Read only**: use ConcurrentDictionary
**Read & Write**: use DataSet

The best concurrent, or Thread-Safe, model, in my opinion, would be the DataSet - see: [ADO.Net Tackle Data Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188748.aspx) and [MSDN DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx). The DataSet was developed to handle in-memory data storage for multiple clients. NOTE what MSDN says:

**This type is safe for multithreaded *read* operations. You must synchronize any write operations.**

You do have an alternative to a DataSet, as Brian Gideon suggests - a ConcurrentDictionary.

With a DataReader, you can fill custom objects, like `DataItem`, directly from the DataReader.

Either way, both of these solutions will allow you quick and concurrent in-memory data access.

Comment: Why would a ConcurrentDictionary need to be read-only? A ConcurrentDictionary has these benefits over a DataSet: faster lookups, and no need for manual synchronization of reads **or** writes (assuming you're not modifying the properties of individual values stored in the dictionary).

Comment: @Joel: *assuming you're not modifying the properties of individual values stored in the dictionary* ... exactly ...

Comment: I guess I shouldn't assume immutable types stored in this dictionary. Makes things so much simpler, though - and it doesn't mean the collection is read-only, since you can easily add, remove, or replace immutable values.

Comment: @Joel: true enough ... I didn't want to assume anything with my answer since the OP didn't explicitly specify any form of immutability, read only, etc.